# Launch a Unity app on in-coming video call in Agora video call SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, call, agora.io

We are using Video Calling SDK for Unity, We want to wake up the app on an incoming call.

**Problem:** 
We send a push notification when the video call starts, we want to ring the phone.
How do we achieve that?

Comment: Do you have a link to _"Video Calling SDK"_ so we can check their docs if they allow such option as "ring the phone"? Is this for Android or iOS? Are you able to at least use native code (not the Unity API) to trigger a phone vibration (through some `IF` statement)?

Answer (score 0):

First, the Agora Video SDK is actually more a "chatting" or streaming SDK. It doesn't include any phone calling capability. You may want to consider building a client-server architecture in handling notifications on the underlying OS. You will need to research on native APIs on how to ring the phone and then build a native bridge to invoke functions from the Unity application layer for further business logic.